# Indicator functions - union of sets

Tags: probability, interval-arithmetic

Given the following expression of two indicator functions:

$$\mathbb{1}_{(-2,0)^2}(x,y) + \mathbb{1}_{[0,2)^2}(x,y)$$

As far as I know, indicator functions can be expressed as one, if the sets are disjoint, such that:

$$\mathbb{1}_{A \cup B} = \mathbb{1}_{A} + \mathbb{1}_{B}$$  (if A and B are disjoint).

But how can I express the union of $(-2,0)^2$ and $[0,2)^2$.

Comment: $(-2,0)^2\cup[0,2)^2$?

Comment: If you are asking if the union of these two is once again a square, the answer is no, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easier way to represent it apart from $$(-2, 0)^2\cup[0,2)^2$$

Comment: Alright, thanks alot! That is what I expected.